# Extend a class in python 3 so that one can iterate over pairs of elements at index i of ls_1 and ls_2. Index i starts at 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to implement the `Pair` class. A `Pair` object contains two lists `ls_1` and `ls_2.`

Then, extend the class so that one can iterate over pairs of elements at `index i` of `ls_1` and `ls_2`. `Index i` starts at `0`.
this is my code so far:

```
class Pair:
    def __init__(self, l, k):
        self.l = l
        self.k = k

    def __iter__(l):
        return Pair(l)

    def __iter__(k):
        return Pair(k)

    def __next__(self):
        x = iter(self.l)
        y = iter(self.k)
        nad = x.__next__()
        raf = y.__next__()
        return (nad,raf)
```

I'm trying to run it with the lists below

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

k = [0, 9, 8]

pair = Pair(l, k)

print(next(pair))  

print(next(pair))  

print(next(pair))  

print(next(pair))
```

I was hoping that it would return something like this:

```
(1,0)

(2,9)

(3,8)

(4, None)
```

But instead I got:

```
(1,0)

(1,0)

(1,0)

(1,0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's hard to understand your code since it's not well formatted, but your problem can be quite simple resolved. Just take a look at below code (it's with comments so should be self-explained).

```
class Pair(object):

    def __init__(self, l, k):
        self._l = l
        self._k = k
        self._index = 0  # Current index in a list

    def __next__(self):
        # Get value form a list using current index value
        # or return None if index is out of range in current list
        x = self._l[self._index] if self._index < len(self._l) else None
        y = self._k[self._index] if self._index < len(self._k) else None
        # Reset index and return self using new index value
        if x is None and y is None:
            self._index = 0
            return next(self)
        # Increase index value and return proper pair of values
        else:
            self._index += 1
            return (x, y)
```

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but from what you have given me, I was able to write the code I wanted